# MYSQL using CASE statement to create a column based on dates

Tags: mysql

There is a column in a table with dates called 'date_activated'. I would like to add a column and use the information from the 'date_activated' to produce a datetime format that sets to the first day of the year.

For example:

| id | date_activated | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 2016-05-12 | 2016-01-01 0:00:00 |
| 2. | 2019-05-16 | 2019-01-01 0:00:00 |

Comment: So you want to alter your table, or just generate a new column via a query?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `ALTER` your table to add your additional column:

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table
ADD COLUMN `datetime` timestamp AFTER date_activated;
```

**Note:** your newly created column named `datetime` is a [Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#:%7E:text=DATE-,DATETIME,-DAY) in MySQL. It is not advised to name things after Keywords or Reserved Words.

---

Next, `UPDATE` your column using an `INNER JOIN` to *self-join* your tables in order to get the year from the `date_activated` column:

```
UPDATE sample_table a
INNER JOIN sample_table b ON a.id = b.id
SET b.datetime = CONCAT(YEAR(b.date_activated), '-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Using `YEAR()`, you can extract the year from `date_activated` then `CONCAT` it with `'-01-01 00:00:00'` to fit your new `timestamp` columns format.

---

If you're just trying to add it to your `SELECT` statement without altering or updating your table:

```
SELECT id, 
       date_activated, 
       CONCAT(YEAR(date_activated), '-01-01 00:00:00') AS datetime
FROM sample_table
```

---

**Input:**

| id | date_activated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-05-12 |
| 2 | 2019-05-16 |

**Output:**

| id | date_activated | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-05-12 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2019-05-16 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/uwA0QVyx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
select
    *,
    cast(concat(year(date_activated), '-1-1') as datetime) 'datetime'
from
    t;
```

and matching output:

| id | date_activated | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-05-12 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2019-05-16 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |

If you want to alter the table you do that, then update the column with the `cast` expression.